# how to display image from path stored in database? in laravel

Tags: php

am developing a site using laravel and I am trying to retrieve images stored as a path in the database but my code only gets the name of the image and the price in the views. I suspect its how i am calling the images as laravel has stored them in the storage/public folder. Please help.
Here is my code: 
@section('content')

```
<div class="container">


    @foreach ($products->chunk(4) as $items)
        <div class="row">
            @foreach ($items as $products)
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <div class="caption text-center">
                            <a href="{{ url('shop', [$products->slug]) }}"><img src="{{ URL::asset('public/' . $products->path) }}" alt="products" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            <h3>{{ $products->name }}</h3>
                            <div class="clearfix">
                            <div class="price pull-left"><p>{{ $products->price }}</p></div>
                            <a href="{{ url('shop', [$products->slug]) }}" class="btn btn-success pull-right" role="button">add to Cart</a>
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- end caption -->
                    </div> <!-- end thumbnail -->
                </div> <!-- end col-md-3 -->
            @endforeach
        </div> <!-- end row -->
    @endforeach

</div> <!-- end container -->
```

Then in my controller:
if($request->hasFile('file')){
            $uploaded_file = $request->file('file');

```
        // this get the original extention
        $uploaded_file_ex = $uploaded_file->getClientOriginalExtension();


        // the path to store the file
        // I add the time at the begining to avoid overwritting the file if another file has the same name.
        $filename = time().'.'.$uploaded_file_ex;
        $path = $uploaded_file->storeAs('public', $filename);
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: @Chalo Your images in public folder directly? If your images is not having fix path then you can also send $path in view from controller.

Comment: Yes they are. what do you mean by sending the $path in view

Comment: $path you can use if you are sending dynamic path for every image

Comment: but if you are storing all images in public folder only and have fix path then no need

Comment: But don't give public in asset. Give like {{ asset($products->path) }}

Comment: But make sure $products->path contains the complete path of your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `images` or some other folder where you will store your images in place of `public` directly. Even if you want to store your images in `public` folder then no need to give `public` in asset. It will pick from `public` folder by default and if you are using dynamic path for images then you must send `$path` from your controller method to view.

Below code will help you if you are directly getting images from public folder.

```
<div class="container">
@foreach ($products->chunk(4) as $items)
    <div class="row">
        @foreach ($items as $products)
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <div class="caption text-center">
                        <a href="{{ url('shop', [$products->slug]) }}"><img 
src="{{ URL::asset($products->path) }}" alt="products" class="img-
responsive"></a>
                        <h3>{{ $products->name }}</h3>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                        <div class="price pull-left"><p>{{ $products->price 
}}</p></div>
                        <a href="{{ url('shop', [$products->slug]) }}" 
class="btn btn-success pull-right" role="button">add to Cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- end caption -->
                </div> <!-- end thumbnail -->
            </div> <!-- end col-md-3 -->
        @endforeach
    </div> <!-- end row -->
@endforeach

</div> <!-- end container -->
```

Upload Image Script that you need to add in your controller method where you are receiving your data from form :-

```
// Upload Image Script
if($request->hasFile('image')){
    if (Input::file('image')->isValid()) {
         $file = Input::file('image');
         $destination = 'img/';
         $extension = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
         $fileName = rand(111,99999).'.'.$extension;
         $file->move($destination, $fileName);
     }
 }
```

Comment: oh, I get could you please help me with how i send $path from my controller to view am kinda lost there

Comment: First tell me what are you getting in $products->path that you are using in asset to get image?

Comment: the images that i have uploaded, the path is stored in the db but the image is stored in the storage folder,, I am getting the images from public/img folder

Comment: if images are in public/img folder then update like src="{{ asset('img/' . $products->path) }}"

Comment: That is where i am retrieving from then storing them in the storage folder via the path in the database

Comment: I can't able to get your point. Your image is located in storage folder or public folder?

Comment: okay i have images in my public folder then when i insert the image it is stored in the storage folder under the folder i have specified in my code..

Comment: Means you want to store your images at storage folder?

Comment: you know storage path is directly unavailable for public?

Comment: You must use storage folder for images if you want to keep them much secure otherwise no need for normal usage. Because it's bit tricky to get images from storage folder for showing in view.

Comment: oh so how should my insert image look like to store it in the public folder??

Comment: Yes we can add images in public folder. do I attach its code in my answer?

Comment: We simply need to add in some folder like img that you have created in public folder and show it in view very easily.

Comment: Add me at FB https://www.facebook.com/amitg100 I will try my best to sort out your issue.

Comment: I have added upload image script that will work in your Laravel project

Comment: images will get uploaded in img folder that you have to create in public folder.